# ExternalInterface call from flash to Javascript OOP object

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, actionscript

This is my problem:

I have this class in JavaScript:

```
var c = new MyClass();
c.myFunction();
c.myFunction2();
c.myFunction3();
//and so on...
```

How can I reference this with `ExternalInterface.call`?

I can't do this: `ExternalInterface.call("c.myFunction"));`

Answer (score 4):

In order for this to work, the object you are trying to call from Flash needs to have global scope. I.e., this will not work:

```
// closure to keep vars out of global scope - generally a good thing!
(function() {
    var c;

    function MyClass() {
    }
    MyClass.prototype.myFunction = function() {
        alert('Do something!');
    }

    c = new MyClass();
})();

... meanwhile, in Flash ...

ExternalInterface.call("c.myFunction");
```

What you need is a global entry-point for the object. What errors are you getting, though? Are you getting `null` back from the call? Is any specific Error being thrown?

Comment: thank you for reminding. when people started using jQuery, they just forget what is what and start wondering why it's not working.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can (do this: ExternalInterface.call("c.myFunction")).

Comment: It doesn't work Omer. I don't see a difference from what I posted.

Comment: +1 It should work, if its not you have a bug some where else. What scope is "c" in?

Answer (score 0):

Publish it to a server and call the html page that way.
ExternalInterface has issues when running in the flex project file system.
Mostlikely its an embed/crossdomain issue.